# Solution verification: check if $H_t(x)= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}$ is approximate identity

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, solution-verification

Let $H_t(x)= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}$, $t>0$. Show that $H_t(x)$ is an approximate identity on $\mathbb{R}$ when $t\rightarrow 0$.

I need to check the third property of the approximate identity. Here is my solution, can someone just check if this is correct:

$$I = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi t}} \int_{|x|> \delta} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}} dx  =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi t}} \int_{|x|> \delta} e^{-(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}})^2} dx .$$

Substitute: $u= \frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}} $, $ du= \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{t}} $:

$$I= \frac{1}{ \sqrt{\pi }} \int_{|u|> \frac{\delta}{2\sqrt{t}}} e^{-u^2}  du .$$
Then since $t \rightarrow 0 $ we have $ \frac{\delta}{2\sqrt{t}}  \rightarrow  \infty$. Function  $ e^{-u^2} $ is integrable, so  $I \rightarrow 0$.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [nascent delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Approximations_to_the_identity) $\tfrac{1}{\epsilon}\eta(\tfrac{x}{\epsilon})$ with $\epsilon:=\sqrt{t}$ and $\eta(z):=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-z^2/4)$ a PDF for which $\eta(0)>0$, namely that of a Normal distribution with $\mu=0,\,\sigma^2=2$.